# Is there a safe way to use setjmp() and longjmp() in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, coroutine

I was under the impression that using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` in C++ was almost guaranteed to mess up the stack, since these functions don't perform unwinding like, say, exceptions do. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2ez4as%28VS.80%29.aspx), however, indicates that the Microsoft implementation can be told to invoke the destructors of local objects, which implies that careful use of these functions could be safe.

Is there a portable means of ensuring program correctness when using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` in C++? Best practices in C++ indicate that exceptions are best not used for flow control, but in a situation that requires highly unusual flow (e.g., coroutines and closures), is it always preferable to use exceptions in lieu of these functions?

Comment: For coroutines, see [ *How do you implement Coroutines in C++* ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121757/how-do-you-implement-coroutines-in-c).

Comment: "in a situation that requires highly unusual flow" it is really better to ask how to implement that particular *unusual workflow*. Abstract questions seldom bear useful answers.

Comment: @Dummy00001: I was referring in general to the various uses of `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` by offering examples of unusual control constructs, not trying to imply that I'm up to some other sort of flow control black magic. I was only asking whether there's a safe way to use these functions in C++, and I got my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some really weird requirement that doesn't allow you to control the flow of the program normally, with conditionals/loops/breaks, I would prefer to use an exception over jmp.

There are scenarios where using an exception to control flow is acceptable. I think one of Boost.Graph's search functions throws an exception to quickly return to the caller from deep recursion.

Comment: Well, then, I'll prefer exceptions. I'd still like to know whether it's *possible* to get away with `*jmp()`, though.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do it while retaining portability. I just tested on Windows with Visual Studio and Linux with gcc. The VS implementation called destructors correctly. The gcc implementation didn't destruct objects that were removed from the stack.

Comment: I had the case where I was creating a wrapper around an old C library (don't remember which one) ; this library required me to pass callback functions, and some parts of that library (that I called inside the callbacks) where using longjmp. This is the kind of code I hope I'll never have to debug

Answer (score 1):

I've used them before, but only under one circumstance: I was creating an OS kernel in C for an OS class; they were used for exception handling.

My understanding is that they're used for exception handling when dealing with low-level code, like an operating system. For general C++ software, I'd just use `try` `catch`.