# Linux open(path, O_NONBLOCK | O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT) blocks pread on file

Tags: linux, file, asynchronous, posix, aio

I want to have async disk read in my program.

There are many HDD on server and if one hdd is slow, program is blocking. I want to make calls async.

If I call:

open(path, O_NONBLOCK | O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT)

and then pread, then pread uses up to 8000 microseconds, but blocks my program.

Is it possible to enable async disk read without thread pool?

Answer (score 5):

The `O_NONBLOCK` flag doesn't have any effect (in most cases at least) for normal files because they are not considered to be something where I/O can block - yes it will block for the length of time taken to read the data from the disk but it won't block for indefinite periods of time like a socket or pipe might.

One exception is when mandatory locking is enabled - then a read or write of a locked region might block for an indefinite period (until the lock is released) and `O_NONBLOCK` will affect how such calls behave.

As to whether asynchronous I/O is possible without threads, the answer is yes (see `aio(7)` or `io_setup(2)`, `io_submit(2)` and friends) but I'd be surprised if you see much benefit from it.