# How to concurrently execute a function without using threads

Tags: c++, c, concurrent-programming

I have a server program that sends clients' data to another that processes it. But because a function can take a long time to execute and prevent the program to work on other clients' data I want to concurrently execute the same function on others' data, without using pthreads or creating processes.

I tried to create something that can do that but it's ugly and surely not the best way. Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

struct userdata {
    int rt; //The 'func' function uses it to resume work where it returned the last time
    int len; //The length of 'data'
    char data[16384]; //Client's data
};

int func(userdata *ud)
{
    //The gotos are here to jump to the code where the function returned the last time
    if(ud->rt==1)goto P1;
    if(ud->rt==2)goto P2;

    ud->len=0;

    //Code to calculate the length of 'data'
    while(ud->data[ud->len]!=0)
    {
        ud->rt=1; //Set to 1 to indicate where to resume execution the next time we will process the same data
        return 0;
        P1:
        ud->len++;
    }
    // Work
    ud->rt=2;
    return 0;
    P2:
    // Work

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    userdata ud;
    memset(ud.data,1,16383);
    ud.data[16383]=0;

    std::vector<userdata> vec;
    for(int i=0;i!=200;i++)vec.push_back(ud); //Add 200 times the structure in the vector
    unsigned int Sz=vec.size(); //I'll use Sz in the for loop to avoid calling size()

    bool Loop=true;
    do
    {
        for(int i=0;i!=Sz;i++)
        {
            if( func(&vec.at(i))==1) //If the function returned 1 this means that there's no more work to do
            {
                printf("str length = %i\n",vec.at(i).len); //Display the result
                vec.erase(vec.begin() + i); //Remove element from vector because there's no more work to do
                i--, Sz--; //Decrement Sz (size of the vector) and i (vector index) to avoid out_of_range exception
                if(Sz==0)Loop=false; //If there are no elements in the vector, leave Loop
            }
        }
    }
    while(Loop);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that this isn't concurrent execution, I must place in the structure the variables that must be restored to their last state and this can take a lot of time when the vector contains thousands of elements.

Comment: Where is the concurrency here? I have literally no idea what this question is about. Your code is as clear as mud and has zero documenting comments. Why?

Comment: Well, there's a technique to have some kind of _signal interrupt/reaction_ manner of organizing execution called [co-routines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121757/how-do-you-implement-coroutines-in-c). Though I'm not convinced this really would help for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"Where is the concurrency here?"_ There's none evident, because the OP avoided it perhaps?

Comment: _@ChkLst_ What you have looks like a poorly flawed scheduler, please learn more about [minimal OS implementation](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_deDE406&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B+minimal+OS+implementation)

Comment: I'm sorry, the sentence before the code isn't exact. What I tried to do create is a code to process different data without having to wait the end of the function. I posted this code to help people to see more clearly what I'm expecting : Execute a function on another client's data without waiting the end of the same function that processes another client's data.

Comment: I think I see what you are doing. You want to be able to partial process the data and alternate between which data is being processed so that both jobs end at roughly the same time? If that is so, I would say you don't need one function that decides which type of data it is working on. You need one function per type of data and design each function to work in chunks. Having one function process different types of data is terribly obscure and hard to maintain.

Comment: I think coroutines may be the answer, thanks ! @Galik Yes that's what this code does. To design a function that works in chuncks sounds interesting, I'll think about it. Thanks !

Comment: @ChkLst: reinventing concurrency is not a good way to avoid concurrency.

Comment: Unfortunately, some devs are mobidly afeared of conventional multithreading.  Having seen several 'tutorial' sites, and some questions/answers on SO, I can understand the threadfunk, but don't agree with it.

Comment: 'I have to drive a nail.  I do have a hammer, but I don't want to use it'.

Comment: @MartinJames You don't understand why I don't want to use a hammer. I want another one. I can use pthreads to do what I want, but I have reasons not to do so. If I said that I want to manage multiple connections in parallel without using threads, would you say the same ? We have non-blocking sockets, poll(), epoll(), etc. [link](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=pthreads+limits) You can find a lot of information from here and see how often people say that there are limits imposed by different things and that one thread per something is not a good idea. I'm trying to find something lighter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to write your own general-purpose threading library, it will be more costly than pthreads. Instead, split up the problem using knowledge from your specific problem. Find a place where it makes *sense* to .

I assume you already have a main loop that just calls `select`/`poll`/`epoll` a bunch. If you don't already have a timeout, start using one so you can store a set of additional, timed, even triggers in a heap.

Then in each computation, stop after a certain number of iterations a schedule a function+data to be called. Use the *current* time (at the end, as opposed to the time that the current timer event started running). Assuming that time actually passes, the timer dispatcher will finish all computations for the oldest tick first before continuing to the next step of the new one (approximately the behavior of a round-robin scheduler). Note that you do *not* want to make the slice size too small, or the task-switching overhead will start to dominate.

Depending on your problem set, you may or may not want to add logic to cancel any upcoming timers if the associated client dies.

Comment: "Don't try to write your own general-purpose threading library" has nothing to do with being an answer to the question.

Comment: @MichaelGazonda it has *everything* to do with the way the OP's *code* is written though.

Comment: sounds like an issue for a comment, not an answer, and certainly not the opening paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. A threading mechanism is difficult. Whatever you do will be buggier and slower than what your system provides.

Copying data in and out of the data structure used by the function is a strange approach. Where would you put it? The normal approach to threading is to have one stack per thread (each thread has both a call stack and a data stack). Each thread executes one instance of the function, and if memory is allocated on the heap, each instance of the problem is stored in different heap locations (so the stack and register in each thread will contain pointers to different heap regions).

Comment: "Don't try to reinvent the wheel. A threading mechanism is difficult. Whatever you do will be buggier and slower than what your system provides." Doesn't attempt to answer the question, and implies a specific intent on the part of the person asking the question that may not be there.

Comment: @MichaelGazonda I suggest that you read the question. Starting with its title — “How to concurrently execute a function without using threads”, and going on with the question body, especially the last paragraph. Concurrently executing [multiple instances of] a function is a threading mechanism (whether you call it by name or not doesn't make it less of one). My second paragraph addresses the approach to context switching outlined in the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @Gilles But is there something lighter than threads ? On several websites I've read that the maximum number of threads isn't very high. I saw 32000 somewhere. Not enough for me.

Comment: @ChkLst What you're asking for *is* a thread mechanism, whether you use the standard one and roll your own. Do you really have enough memory and CPU power to run more than 32000 threads at the same time? If you put a 1ms time slice for each thread, they'd only get to execute barely twice a minute!