# C++ "continue-able" loop after fast loop exit: Is it a good practice?

Tags: c++

I am going to write a function containing loops, which can be continued later on by saved loop environment.  Is the following sample program a good practice (see codes below)? Yet `goto` is used in the example: is that good or bad?

Another way I think of is to create a class containing an iterator.  But it seems to be more complex to deal with all those iterator codes.

`main()` function in the example just illustrates how to call the "continue-able" function.  My real codes may contain two of those `find1()` function, (say, `find1()` and `find2()`). Depending on situations, I select which function to continue the finding process (after examine the relationship of the results from `find1()` and `find2()`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

struct IdxPair
{
    int i;
    int j;
};

// finder predicate function: In the real world, this function could be big.
bool pred(int i, int j)
{
    return (i+j == 8);
}

// result generating function: In the real world, this function could be big.
int calc(int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}

int find1(bool isFirstLoop)
{
    int i, j;
    static IdxPair toBeContinued;

    if (isFirstLoop) {
        // It's the first time: setup initial values
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
    } else {
        i = toBeContinued.i;
        j = toBeContinued.j;
        goto continueLoop;
    }

    // sample loop:
    // In the real world, it could be more layer of nested loops.
    // The lower/upper limits for i, j could be from functions
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
            cout << "(i, j) = (" << i << ", " << j << ")" << endl;
            if (pred(i,j)) {
                toBeContinued.i = i;
                toBeContinued.j = j;
                return calc(i, j);  // so-called "fast loop exit"
            }
            continueLoop:
            ;
        }
    }
    return INT_MIN;
}


int main()
{
    int result=0;  // Set it to something other than INT_MIN.
    for (result=find1(true); result != INT_MIN; result=find1(false)) {
        cout << "result = " << result << endl;
    }
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl;
}
```

--Update--
Some may ask why I want this in the first place?  Yes, it's a good question: I welcome answers to solve the problem without using "continue-able" loop design.
Forgive my poor creativity, I can't think of how to do it without "continue-able" loop.

Comment: It looks like you are implementing coroutine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121757/how-do-you-implement-coroutines-in-c

Comment: While I agree that coroutines would sometimes be useful, this case doesn't need them. You can just have a class that stores i and j, with methods (possibly called * and ++) to get the next element.

Comment: Boost can also help with filter/transform iterators so you can concentrate on indexes.