# Is it possible to return many values from a loop in a function? C++

Tags: c++, function, loops

Would it be possible to return many values from a loop within a function, something along the lines of this:

```
float MyFunc(float First, float Second)
{
    while (First < Second)
    {
        First++;
        return First;
    }
}
```

And then be able to i.e print out the different values as they are returned?

(I understand as is this is not a very good way to do anything, but I was just curious and couldn't seem to find a good answer to this specifically. Maybe I just wasn't looking hard enough)

Comment: Use vector to store and return.

Comment: What you are looking for is [coroutines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121757/how-do-you-implement-coroutines-in-c). They are not part of the standard yet, but there are plans to include them in c++17.

Comment: You could return a more complex datatype, or pass in an array/vector by reference and modify that.

Comment: @Fang 's proposal is the most correct (yet overspec, at times...) approach IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With coroutines (working under Visual Studio 2015 Update 3) it would look like this:

```
generator<float> MyFunc(float First, float Second) {
  while (First < Second) {
      First++;
      co_yield First;
  }
}
```

And then you could write

```
for (auto && i : MyFunc(2,7)) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
```

There is a talk about this on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw

See here for exactly your example: https://youtu.be/ZTqHjjm86Bw?t=40m10s

If you do not want to wait for coroutines, have a look at the boost::range library.

Or implement your own kind-of iterator

```
struct counter {
  counter (int first, int last) : counter {first, last, first} {}
  counter begin () const { return counter {first, last, first}; }
  counter end () const { return counter {first, last, last}; }
  int operator++ () { ++current; }
  int operator* () const { return current; }
private:
  counter (int first, int last, int current)
    : first (first), last (last), current (current)
    {}
  int first, last, current;
};

bool operator != (counter a, counter b) { return *a != *b; }

int main() {
    for (auto && i : counter {2,5}) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return a vector.

```
std::vector<float> MyFunc(float First, float Second)
{
    std::vector<float> Result;
    while (First < Second)
    {
        First++;
        Result.push_back(First);
    }
    return(Result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- While you cannot return like that there are several ways you could do
  that. Firstly, put all the results in an array or vector, then return
  at the end. However, this wouldn't mean printing them out the moment
  they are returned.
- You could call the print function inside the loop, this would make sure they are printed instantly and then return the vector at the end. But this doesn't quite seem like what you want either.
- You could also attempt something using multi threading. Adding the results to some form of a concurrent queue and then having another thread processing elements from the queue and printing them out. This is closest to what I think you want but is significantly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood your problenm correctly , you can do something like this
and print your array;

```
std::vector<float> MyFunc(float First, float Second)
    {
   std::vector<float> arr(50);
    int i=0;
        while (First < Second)
        {
            First++;
            arr[i]=first;
            i++;
        }
    return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Please change that to use `std::vector<float>` instead of an array of float.